# GemBox Retrieving Calculated Values From a ExcelWorkSheet #VALUE

Tags: java, excel

I am working with `Gembox.Spreadsheet.ExcelWorksheet`. I have given the input values for an `ExcelWorksheet` and tried to get the output result from another `ExcelWorksheet`. But at that point after I gave the input, I have called `ExcelFile.calculate()` method to evaluate for all worksheets' formulas and set the results.

Then I have tried to get the result from other `ExcelWorksheet`, but it returns only **#VALUE!** for that cell. The weird thing is if I am going to save this file after the evaluation and then manually open it, I could see the results on that cell clearly. I have also tried to get the result after saving on a file, and tried to get the result on that, it is still **#VALUE!**.

Any help or idea would be appreciated. I am really stuck.

Comment: First note, when you open the file in some Excel application it will automatically recalculate formulas, this is why you don't see "#VALUE!". Now regarding the calculate issue, are you using external references in your formulas? If yes, I'm afraid that GemBox.Spreadsheet's calculation engine currently doesn't support those.

Comment: What do you mean external references? I have used if,vlookup etc methods on the result spreadsheet but i need to evaluate these methods with using some values which are on previous spreadsheet/spreadsheets. Otherwise, i do not use any external references.All the references are on the spreadsheets that if i need to evaluate something

Comment: And one more thing that i am confused.You said the excel automatically recalculates  formulas.If so, after calculation i can save the file with this result right? At that point i have got still  **#VALUE!**

Comment: By external references I meant referencing one Excel file in the formula of another Excel file, that is what I presumed you had. Unfortunately, without taking a look at your file and investigating it I cannot say what the problem is. Also yes, after opening and saving the file with MS Excel, it should contain the last calculated values and you should be able to read them. However, if you again call "calculate" method then you will again get "#VALUE!". If this is not your case (you're not calling "calculate" again) then you'll need to show me the file and the code that you're using.